# would you know why I am getting the error $ is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fivem

everything was working fine a few days ago and since yesterday I have this error on my FiveM server.

So I understood that the error came from jquery and I therefore went to see the file concerned.
We can see in the error message that the error is in line 9 and line 94 of the inventory.js file, if we look a little bit we can think that the variable $ of Jquery is not defined because of a bad call, strange since it worked until yesterday but why not, so let's see in the html file if our call is correct.

When we look at the html file we can see that Jquery is called before our inventory.js file however $ is not defined so I tried to put a $ (document) .ready (function () {}); which would encompass all the part with errors but this time it is the $ of $ (document) which is not defined, so the problem does not come from there.

I also tried to update Jquery with no success, I tried to update my script with no success as well.

And I tried to put Jquery in Dur earlier than in CDN but again it didn't work.

So I tried to put back a backup of when it was working so that I could perhaps locate the problem, but to my regret the backup was not working either.

If you think you can help me don't hesitate, I don't know what to do at all.

I give you all the useful information below to better understand the problem.

Regards

```js
var type = "normal";
var disabled = false;

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.data.action == "display") {
        type = event.data.type
        disabled = false;

        if (type === "normal") { $(".info-div").hide();} 
        
        else if (type === "trunk") { $(".info-div").show();} 
        
        else if (type === "property") { $(".info-div").hide();} 
        
        else if (type === "glovebox") { $(".info-div").show();} 
        
        else if (type === "vault") { $(".info-div").hide();} 
        
        else if (type === "player") { $(".info-div").show();}

        $(".ui").fadeIn();
    } else if (event.data.action == "hide") {
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        $(".ui").fadeOut();
        $(".item").remove();
        $("#otherInventory").html("<div id=\"noSecondInventoryMessage\"></div>");
        $("#noSecondInventoryMessage").html(invLocale.secondInventoryNotAvailable);
    } else if (event.data.action == "setItems") {
        inventorySetup(event.data.itemList);

        $('.item').draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            appendTo: 'body',
            zIndex: 99999,
            revert: 'invalid',
            start: function (event, ui) {
                if (disabled) {
                    return false;
                }

                $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
                itemData = $(this).data("item");

                if (!itemData.canRemove) {
                    $("#drop").addClass("disabled");
                    $("#give").addClass("disabled");
                }

                if (!itemData.usable) {
                    $("#use").addClass("disabled");
                }
            },
            stop: function () {
                itemData = $(this).data("item");

                if (itemData !== undefined && itemData.name !== undefined) {
                    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(\'img/items/' + itemData.name + '.png\'');
                    $("#drop").removeClass("disabled");
                    $("#use").removeClass("disabled");
                    $("#give").removeClass("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (event.data.action == "setSecondInventoryItems") {
        secondInventorySetup(event.data.itemList);
    } else if (event.data.action == "setInfoText") {
        $(".info-div").html(event.data.text);
    } else if (event.data.action == "nearPlayers") {
        $("#nearPlayers").html("");

        $.each(event.data.players, function (index, player) {
            $("#nearPlayers").append('<button class="nearbyPlayerButton" data-player="' + player.player + '">' + player.label + ' (' + player.player + ')</button>');
        });

        $("#dialog").dialog("open");

        $(".nearbyPlayerButton").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            player = $(this).data("player");
            $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/GiveItem", JSON.stringify({
                player: player,
                item: event.data.item,
                number: parseInt($("#count").val())
            }));
        });
    }
});

function closeInventory() {
    $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/NUIFocusOff", JSON.stringify({}));
}

function inventorySetup(items) {
    $("#playerInventory").html("");
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
        count = setCount(item);

        $("#playerInventory").append('<div class="slot"><div id="item-' + index + '" class="item" style = "background-image: url(\'img/items/' + item.name + '.png\')">' +
            '<div class="item-count">' + count + '</div> <div class="item-name">' + item.label + '</div> </div ><div class="item-name-bg"></div></div>');
        $('#item-' + index).data('item', item);
        $('#item-' + index).data('inventory', "main");
    });
}

function secondInventorySetup(items) {
    $("#otherInventory").html("");
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
        count = setCount(item);

        $("#otherInventory").append('<div class="slot"><div id="itemOther-' + index + '" class="item" style = "background-image: url(\'img/items/' + item.name + '.png\')">' +
            '<div class="item-count">' + count + '</div> <div class="item-name">' + item.label + '</div> </div ><div class="item-name-bg"></div></div>');
        $('#itemOther-' + index).data('item', item);
        $('#itemOther-' + index).data('inventory', "second");
    });
}

function disableInventory(ms) {
    disabled = true;

    setInterval(function () {
        disabled = false;
    }, ms);
}

function setCount(item) {
    count = item.count

    if (item.limit > 0) {
        count = item.count + " / " + item.limit
    }

    if (item.type === "item_weapon") {
        if (count == 0) {
            count = "";
        } else {
            count = '<img src="img/bullet.png" class="ammoIcon"> ' + item.count;
        }
    }

    if (item.type === "item_account" || item.type === "item_money") {
        count = formatMoney(item.count);
    }

    return count;
}

function formatMoney(n, c, d, t) {
    var c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;

    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#count").focus(function () {
        $(this).val("")
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val("1")
        }
    });

    $("body").on("keyup", function (key) {
        if (Config.closeKeys.includes(key.which)) {
            closeInventory();
        }
    });

    $('#use').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hoverControl',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            itemData = ui.draggable.data("item");
            if (itemData.usable) {
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/UseItem", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData
                }));
            }
        }
    });

    $('#give').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hoverControl',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            itemData = ui.draggable.data("item");
            if (itemData.canRemove) {
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/GetNearPlayers", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData
                }));
            }
        }
    });

    $('#drop').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hoverControl',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            itemData = ui.draggable.data("item");
            if (itemData.canRemove) {
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/DropItem", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData,
                    number: parseInt($("#count").val())
                }));
            }
        }
    });

    $('#playerInventory').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            itemData = ui.draggable.data("item");
            itemInventory = ui.draggable.data("inventory");

            if (type === "trunk" && itemInventory === "second") {
                disableInventory(500);
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/TakeFromTrunk", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData,
                    number: parseInt($("#count").val())
                }));
            } else if (type === "property" && itemInventory === "second") {
                disableInventory(500);
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/TakeFromProperty", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData,
                    number: parseInt($("#count").val())
                }));
            } else if (type === "glovebox" && itemInventory === "second") {
                disableInventory(500);
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/TakeFromGlovebox", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData,
                    number: parseInt($("#count").val())
                }));
            } else if (type === "vault" && itemInventory === "second") {
                disableInventory(500);
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/TakeFromVault", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData,
                    number: parseInt($("#count").val())
                }));
            } else if (type === "player" && itemInventory === "second") {
                disableInventory(500);
                $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/TakeFromPlayer", JSON.stringify({
                    item: itemData,
                    number: parseInt($("#count").val())
                }));
            }
        }
    });

    $('#otherInventory').droppable({ drop: function (event, ui) { itemData = ui.draggable.data("item"); itemInventory = ui.draggable.data("inventory");

    if (type === "trunk" && itemInventory === "main") {
        disableInventory(500);
        $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/PutIntoTrunk", JSON.stringify({
            item: itemData,
            number: parseInt($("#count").val())
        }));
    } else if (type === "property" && itemInventory === "main") {
        disableInventory(500);
        $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/PutIntoProperty", JSON.stringify({
            item: itemData,
            number: parseInt($("#count").val())
        }));
    } else if (type === "glovebox" && itemInventory === "main") {
        disableInventory(500);
        $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/PutIntoGlovebox", JSON.stringify({
            item: itemData,
            number: parseInt($("#count").val())
        }));
    } else if (type === "vault" && itemInventory === "main") {
        disableInventory(500);
        $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/PutIntoVault", JSON.stringify({
            item: itemData,
            number: parseInt($("#count").val())
        }));
    } else if (type === "player" && itemInventory === "main") {
        disableInventory(500);
        $.post("http://esx_inventoryhud/PutIntoPlayer", JSON.stringify({
            item: itemData,
            number: parseInt($("#count").val())
        }));
    }
}
});

    $("#count").on("keypress keyup blur", function (event) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
        if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

$.widget('ui.dialog', $.ui.dialog, {
    options: {
        // Determine if clicking outside the dialog shall close it
        clickOutside: false,
        // Element (id or class) that triggers the dialog opening 
        clickOutsideTrigger: ''
    },
    open: function () {
        var clickOutsideTriggerEl = $(this.options.clickOutsideTrigger),
            that = this;
        if (this.options.clickOutside) {
            // Add document wide click handler for the current dialog namespace
            $(document).on('click.ui.dialogClickOutside' + that.eventNamespace, function (event) {
                var $target = $(event.target);
                if ($target.closest($(clickOutsideTriggerEl)).length === 0 &&
                    $target.closest($(that.uiDialog)).length === 0) {
                    that.close();
                }
            });
        }
        // Invoke parent open method
        this._super();
    },
    close: function () {
        // Remove document wide click handler for the current dialog
        $(document).off('click.ui.dialogClickOutside' + this.eventNamespace);
        // Invoke parent close method 
        this._super();
    },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>ESX INVENTORY HUD BY TRSAK</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="locales/fr.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/inventory.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                clickOutside: true
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div class="ui">
        <div class="inventory">
            <div id="playerInventory">
            </div>
            <div id="controls">
                <div class="info-div"></div>
                <div class="controls-div">
                    <input type="number" class="control" id="count" value="1">
                    <div class="control" id="use"></div>
                    <div class="control" id="give"></div>
                    <div class="control" id="drop"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="otherInventory">
                <div id="noSecondInventoryMessage">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dialog">
        <div id="nearPlayers">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#use").html(invLocale.useItem);
        $("#give").html(invLocale.giveItem);
        $("#drop").html(invLocale.dropItem);
        $("#noSecondInventoryMessage").html(invLocale.secondInventoryNotAvailable);
    });
</script>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Check network tab - sounds like jquery.js is not loading, maybe a 404 or 403 denied.  Could be blocked by a new firewall rule somewhere along the line.

Comment: maybe it is from last script is out of body tag.

Comment: @freedomn-m what is strange is that in some players everything works correctly as in my case but in others they get this error however Jquery is well called and if it was a security restriction at the server level, all the players would be impacted, unless it can come from the client side like an antivirus which would block the Jquery call and even if it is the case it would certainly block the external links so normally by hardening Jquery I should not have a problem yet it persists.

Comment: @foadabdollahi I don't think but i'll try

Comment: jquery *is* loaded by the client, not the server.   Specific, individual files can be blocked by firewall/antivirus.  But does sound unlikely.  Your question wording implied it stopped for all users - is that the case, or only specific users?

Comment: @freedomn-m excuse me if i misdescribed my problem my english is not perfect.

Currently I have an increase in players and until yesterday nobody had a problem and yesterday 2 people reported it to me so I did the basic operations to try to solve the problem such as clearing the client and server caches but the problem persisted so I went into the code to see what was going on.

But currently on the server these are the only 2 cases that we have noticed.

nevertheless 2 in the same day is quite a coinidence, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

When you load the .js file make sure is in the `files {}` property of your fxmanifest.lua or __resource.lua. And import jquery before your js file in the html with:

`<script src="nui://game/ui/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`